# How to write CSS / SCSS / PostCSS inside React .tsx file as JavaScript String in VSCode and WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webstorm, visual-studio-code

I am trying to set up a new self convention to make my React code better organized like the following:

```
export default function HeaderExample() {
  const compStyle = getStyle();
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <style jsx>{compStyle}</style>
    </>
  )
}

function getStyle() {
  return `
        h1 {
          color: blue;
        }
      `
}
```

It works fine, but writing the return in `getStyle()` is pretty hard because I don't get formatting or syntax highlight help from the IDE.

How can I get those? Plugin / Library / Setting / Giving it a type? Any of those will help.

And at the same chance, do you think this can cause any issues down the road?

Comment: `return css\` ....` -- it gets colored for me (and offers CSS code completion) https://i.imgur.com/9eKQCMS.png For that I had to clone bundled Language Injection rule for `html` and adjust it to be CSS (so no need for manual injections) https://i.imgur.com/tKVXM7O.png . **Please note:** I'm not JavaScript person _at all_ and do not know if just prefixing a template string with `css` is enough -- maybe some actual code is also needed (that handles that `css` prefix in some way).

Comment: webstorm --> // language=CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebStorm has a built-in feature `Language Injection`. for that.

[Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-language-injections.html) you will find in detail documentation of that feature.

Short version.

1. Place your cursor in the relevant code block and click `alt + enter`.

[image]

2. In the DropDown, select `Inject language or reference`. Without clicking to the right, click `enter` again.

[image]

3. A window should open, now select the language you like to inject. If you select `CSS` the result should be:

[image]

To answer your second question. It shouldn't cause any trouble down the road.

edit addition:

It is possible to trigger the same behaviour with a comment `laguange=css`

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! that solves it, do you know if there's maybe an easier way like @Arjit Tiwari offered for vscode? As it gets repetitive to do it for every component?

Comment: I don't know another way, but I think it should be possible to automate this. If you are using styles like that in many places, also take a look at `Styled Components`.

Comment: @eliezra236 just found out you can do the same as Arjit Tiwari wrote for VSCode in Webstorm with `// language=CSS`. See my edit.

Comment: For the automation, also see documentation on language injection rules definition

Answer (score 1):

In vscode you can use [ES6 String css](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bashmish.es6-string-css) vscode extension

Just add `/*css*/` before ` like this

```
function getStyle() {
  return /*css*/`
        h1 {
          color: blue;
        }
      `
}
```

Comment: Is there anything similar for WebStorm?

Comment: I do not use Webstorm for web development, I think you can use Language Injection for Webstorm